# Retrieve the ajax call line in the script

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a module installed on the site and that includes many scripts that has been predefined by the module maker.However , scripts includes an ajax call to load the image but the path  they have provided is wrong in relative to my localhost.Which shows an error in the console window

> GET abc.png Not Found

I checked using **Firebug** console but i dont seem to get the line where the call has been made.Is there any way to get the line no or some reference as to know where this call has been made?

Comment: In chrome you have an option. Developer Tools > Network. You can see all the requests and it has column called "Initiater" when u do a mouse over on it, it will show the stacktrace for your request.

Comment: It says other.What does that mean?